Read android.media.Image.hardwareBuffer as opengl texture
In Android using Kotlin and camera2.
How do you read image.hardwareBuffer as opengl texture in this section?
val onImageAvailableListener = ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener { reader ->
            val image = reader.acquireLatestImage()
            if(image != null && image.hardwareBuffer != null){
                //read image.hardwareBuffer in opengl es 3.0
                image.close()
            }
        }

Searching around what think I need.
eglGetNativeClientBufferANDROID()
eglCreateImageKHR()
glEGLImageTargetTexture2DOES()
eglClientWaitSyncKHR()

Which are all only avaliable in c++?
Is there another simpler way without using c++?
If not then can you write an example that puts those functions togheter to be able to read the texture in a opengl es 3.0 shader?

The simplest option would be not to use an ImageReader at all, and switch to a SurfaceTexture which is designed for reading frames into the GPU.
If that's not feasible, you need to ensure the ImageReader.newInstance() includes the USAGE_GPU_SAMPLED_IMAGE flag.
Then you can convert the Image to a HardwareBuffer via Image.getHardwareBuffer().  Then you can wrap that in an EGL texture; that may have to be done in native code, I can't find a quick reference for the right EGL calls.  But looks like you might want eglCreateImageFromHardwareBuffer and glEGLImageTargetTexture2DOES to do the necessary steps.
So if possible, stick to SurfaceTexture.
